# Docker to store an application(service) logs in a folder and purge them on a timely basis

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot, webmin

I just had a query of storing the logs of a service/application in a separate folder and purge them frequently.

We use Docker in Webmin server to deploy our Spring boot Application. we would like to achieve the above to prevent the space mess in webmin server

Below is a sample command we use to build and run the service,

```
docker build -t application-service:latest ./application-service
docker run -p 1070:1070 -m 128m -d application-service
```

I used "-m" for memory allocation of a service And, I just wonder, is there any key to store the logs of the application in different path and any other things which i can do in docker or webmin server to purge the logs in that particular location

Thanks in advance !!! Awaiting for a suggestion !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker has a number ways of handling the container logs. You can read about them [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/).

All you need is to provide the logging driver you need, while you call `docker run` with the `--log-driver` flag specifying the driver and it's configuration.

One more possible solution is to use mounted volumes and configure your service, which is running within container, to store it's logs into the folder, which should be mounted. In that case, you will have access to the logs in your host-machine.

Comment: Hi @Stanislav, it's a good info. I can check on max-file of json driver. I need an option to store logs in separate where it should not be removed while I do remove docker command

Comment: @ChellaKumaran I'm pretty sure, that logs stored with driver doesn't disappear on container deletion as it's happens then no driver selected. Atleast `syslog` crates a separate file with logs, which is available even after container removement.

Comment: But syslog driver needs a separate machine ip address to export the logs right. I need to export the logs within the server in different folder. Is it feasible ?

Comment: @ChellaKumaran with syslog you can use host machine ip too, to store it on the same server. And to use syslog is just a suggestion, may be some other driver will be more suitable for your exact case